# Bind address in Sinatra Application

Tags: sinatra, bind, memory-address

I'm running a classic style application in Sinatra and I would like to obtain a URL which the application is bound to. For example, if I start it in a development environment I would expect to get: `http://localhost:4567/` while in production environment this would point to: `http://example.com/`
I know it is possible to retrieve it from the request.  However, I need it in configuration block. How to do it?

Comment: You probably want to set up a reverse proxy to deal with slow clients.

Answer (score 6):

Use the bind host and bind port method:

```
set :bind, 'example.com'
set :port, 80
```

should work.
taken from [here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html). at the beginning of the page you can find how to implement them in you app (just copy it in front of your gets)

Comment: To add to @ben 's answer:  You can have more than one bind name  `set :bind, 'example.com','mysecondhost' `  and sinatra server will listen to all of those.